# MongoDB count all unique people born in different locations

Tags: mongodb

I'm currently working with a MongoDB database and I want to extract all the unique people born in all the places used. So if people have the same name and age then I would only count that as one for that location. I am using MongoDB Version 3.2 so any answers would need to be in that if possible.
An example of the document is:

```
[
    {
        '_id': 1,
        'Users': [
            {
                'name': 'John Davies',
                'age': NumberLong(35),
                'place_of_birth': 'France',
            },
            {
                'name': 'Edward Jones',
                'age': 'blank',
                'place_of_birth': 'Spain',
            },
            {
                'name': 'Daniel Rhys',
                'age': NumberLong(63),
                'place_of_birth': 'France',
            },
            {
                'name': 'Evan Williams',
                'age': NumberLong(21),
                'place_of_birth': 'France',
            },
            {
                'name': 'John Davies',
                'age': NumberLong(35),
                'place_of_birth': 'France',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        '_id': 2,
        'Users': [
            {
                'name': 'John Davies',
                'age': NumberLong(35),
                'place_of_birth': 'Italy',
            },
            {
                'name': 'Edward Jones',
                'age': 'blank',
                'place_of_birth': 'Spain',
            },
            {
                'name': 'Daniel Rhys',
                'age': NumberLong(63),
                'place_of_birth': 'Italy',
            },
            {
                'name': 'Evan Williams',
                'age': NumberLong(61),
                'place_of_birth': 'France',
            },
            {
                'name': 'John Davies',
                'age': NumberLong(21),
                'place_of_birth': 'France',
            },
        ],
    },
]
```

At the moment I can only get the total of whatever location I am inputting, but I would like to get the total for all of them. There are more places of birth in the actual document so I cant just input them all individually.
My current code looks like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$Users"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "Users.place_of_birth": "France"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "null",
      "people": {
        "$addToSet": {
          "Name": "$Users.name",
          "Age": "$Users.age",
          "Place of birth": "$Users.place_of_birth"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "Place of birth": "$_id.place_of_birth",
      "total": {
        "$size": "$people"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The current output is just:

```
[
  {
    "total": 5
  }
]
```

But I would like to have the output of:
France: 5
Spain: 1
Italy: 2
etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very very close, all you have to do is change the `_id` in the `$group` stage to be the country of the user, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$Users"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$Users.place_of_birth",
      "people": {
        "$addToSet": {
          "Name": "$Users.name",
          "Age": "$Users.age",
          "Place of birth": "$Users.place_of_birth"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "Place of birth": "$_id.place_of_birth",
      "total": {
        "$size": "$people"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/F23cZgsUBmQ)